# How to keep next() function from hiding on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple jquery menu and I am trying to keep the submenu visible if a user hover overs it. so that I can select it if needed. However, when I get off the hover element the submenu will hide. Obviously, that's what I want as long as it's not also hovering over the submenu.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mainBar li a').hover(function(){
        $(this).next().show() }, function () {
            $(this).next().stop().hide()
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/azxRX/1/

Comment: Can you share some markup and maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle is in the question. here it is if for some reason you can't see it. http://jsfiddle.net/azxRX/1/ Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinion is to create this menus with css. Anyway i change a bit to this:

```
$('.sideBar > ul > li').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);//This line sets it up so that when the mouse is moved over a li in myMenu, the function openSubMenu is called

$('.sideBar > ul > li').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);//This do exacly the same with the above but binds on mouseout instead.

function openSubMenu() {
///when the mouse rolls over the list item,
///the function looks for an unordered list within it.
///If one is found, it sets the style property display to block
    $(this).find('ul').css('display', 'block'); 
};

function closeSubMenu() {
///This one does the oposite of openSubMenu function
    $(this).find('ul').css('display', 'none');  
};
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/azxRX/16/)

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue!! I will look into doing this with CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mainBar li').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.subBar').show();
        console.log('over');
    });
    $('.mainBar li').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).find('.subBar').hide();
    });
});
```

This is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azxRX/1/)**